# Add a color bar or common legend to a layout of multiple heatmaps

Tags: r, grid, heatmap

I have this code to plot multiple heatmaps together. But, I can't seem to find a way to add a common legend to it. Many have suggested using ggplot, but I am not very comfortable with it. I tried it but it never seems to work for me. I never seem to get it right.

so, I was wondering if there's a trick to add a common legend or even a color bar here (vertically on one side or horizontally at the bottom) over the already plotted `heatmap`. I used `grid` package to manually add labels to the plots but can't seem to find a way to add a color bar as well.

Please help me out.

```
library(pacman)
pacman::p_load(gridGraphics,grid,gridExtra,gplots,lubridate, install = TRUE)
    
#file = "I:/heatmap_month.xlsx"       

## load all sheets
#sheets <- openxlsx::getSheetNames(file)
#SheetList <- lapply(sheets,openxlsx::read.xlsx,xlsxFile=file)
#names(SheetList) <- sheets


#Define a new function to create row and col labels
cname <- function(i){
  if (i <= 30) {
    cname = format(ymd(seq(as.Date("1982-01-01"), as.Date("2017-12-01"), by = "years")), "%Y")
  } else if (i <= 33) {
    cname = format(ymd(seq(as.Date("2021-01-01"), as.Date("2060-12-01"), by = "years")), "%Y")
  } else {
    cname = format(ymd(seq(as.Date("2061-01-01"), as.Date("2100-12-01"), by = "years")), "%Y")
  }
}

rname = c("Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May", "June", "July", "Aug", "Sep", "Oct", "Nov", "Dec")

## create color ramp and colour breaks
col_breaks <- c(-2,-1.5,-1,0,1,1.5,2)
my_palette<-colorRampPalette(c("red4","red1","darkorange2","gold2",
                               "yellow4","yellow",
                               "chartreuse3","green4"))
#dummy data    
arr <- replicate(6, matrix(sample(1:100),nrow=10,ncol=10), simplify = FALSE)

# define a grob function
    grab_grob <- function(){
      grid.echo()
  grid.grab()
}


   g1 = lapply(1:6, function(i) {
  heatmap.2(as.matrix(arr[[i]]),
            dendrogram ='none',
            Colv=FALSE, Rowv = FALSE, 
            key=FALSE, keysize=1.0, symkey=FALSE, density.info='none',
            trace='none',
            scale="none",cexRow=0.7,cexCol=0.9,
            breaks = col_breaks,col=my_palette,
            labRow = rname,
            labCol = cname(i),
            colsep = 0:ncol(arr[[i]]), sepwidth = c(0.005),
            sepcolor = c("grey")
  )
  
  grab_grob()
}
)


grid.newpage()
title1 = textGrob("MAIN TITLE", gp=gpar(fontface="bold", fontsize = 20), vjust = 0.5)
grid.arrange(grobs = g1, ncol = 3, nrow = 3, clip = TRUE, top = title1)

#Label heatmap in 3rd row
grid::grid.text(label = "Upper: 2061-2100", x = unit(0.17, "npc"), y = unit(0.28, "npc"), 
                gp = gpar(fontface = "bold", col = "gray33", fontsize = 10))
grid::grid.text(label = "Middle: 2061-2100", x = unit(0.5, "npc"), y = unit(0.28, "npc"), 
                gp = gpar(fontface = "bold", col = "gray33", fontsize = 10))
grid::grid.text(label = "Lower: 2061-2100", x = unit(0.83, "npc"), y = unit(0.28, "npc"), 
                gp = gpar(fontface = "bold", col = "gray33", fontsize = 10))

#Label heatmap 2nd row
grid::grid.text(label = "Upper: 2021-2060", x = unit(0.17, "npc"), y = unit(0.60, "npc"), 
                gp = gpar(fontface = "bold", col = "gray33", fontsize = 10))
grid::grid.text(label = "Middle: 2021-2060", x = unit(0.5, "npc"), y = unit(0.60, "npc"), 
                gp = gpar(fontface = "bold", col = "gray33", fontsize = 10))
grid::grid.text(label = "Lower: 2021-2060", x = unit(0.83, "npc"), y = unit(0.60, "npc"), 
                gp = gpar(fontface = "bold", col = "gray33", fontsize = 10))

#Label heatmap in 1st row
grid::grid.text(label = "Upper: 1982-2017", x = unit(0.17, "npc"), y = unit(0.92, "npc"), 
                gp = gpar(fontface = "bold", col = "gray33", fontsize = 10))
grid::grid.text(label = "Middle: 1982-2017", x = unit(0.5, "npc"), y = unit(0.92, "npc"), 
                gp = gpar(fontface = "bold", col = "gray33", fontsize = 10))
grid::grid.text(label = "Lower: 1982-2017", x = unit(0.83, "npc"), y = unit(0.92, "npc"), 
                gp = gpar(fontface = "bold", col = "gray33", fontsize = 10))
```

Comment: There is a bug in your code. It should be `colsep = 0:ncol(arr[[i]]), sepwidth = c(0.005)` when creating `g1`

Comment: Thanks for bringing that to notice. I was using different data that wasn't retrieving from a list. When I added a dummy data here, I forgot to change that portion of the code. Still, thank you for pointing that out.